# getUserIdentityTokenAsync takes too long

Tags: outlook-addin

I am working on an Outlook addin, and we use the JavaScript api to get the User Identity Token.
I recently noticed that many times our app starts really slow in the morning, though after that first load, it works much faster. I pin-pointed the problem on the `getUserIdentityTokenAsync` call we are making before our first request to the server. This morning it took ~11 seconds to return a value. Yesterday I think it was ~18 seconds.
Is there anything I can do about it? Or should I just accept the fact that when the Office context decides it needs to return a new token (I assume that is the case), the function might take a while longer to return? Is there a way to simulate it (Can I invalidate my current token, to force the context into creating a new one)?

Also - we are currently sending the token on every request to the server, where we have a `tokenValidation` middleware that checks its signature, expiration date and audience, before extracting the `msexchuid` for us to use. A request without the token will return 401. Is this a good practice, or should we only validate the token on the first request, and put the Id on the session instead? Is it "safe" enough?